How to draw borders in binary numpy array to split into clusters
I'm looking for an algorithm/preexisting package to draw borders of 1s into an array so that the remaining 0s are split into clusters/globular shapes in 3D, given some seed points for the locations of the clusters. I'm looking for an approach that in 2D would output something like this:

(where black represents 0s, red represents the border of 1s, and green is the seedpoints)
I tried to previously do this using a voronoi tesselation of a 3D space and turning the partitioning edges into planes, but I couldn't get it to work. I'm looking to use this for modeling of grain boundary networks in materials.
Thanks!

My first guess would also be Voronoi. It's not clear to me how many dimensions you have: you mention 2d in the question but then talk about 3d and grain boundaries. And how did you try using Voronoi? I'd expect scipy's to work fine. The hard part would be selecting pixels that contain the boundaries, especially if you want the partitioning to be properly connected. You might need Bresenham or something similar.

I just provided a 2D example for visualization purposes of mapping the partition borders onto an array. I used scipy's voronoi module, and it worked fine, but I had a hard time figuring out how to map the edges onto integer values in a 3D array. The problem more was with figuring out how to map a plane in 3D space onto array sites.

Yes, sorry, I just finished rereading your question.

I can think of two naive approaches. 1: for each pixel find the distance to each seed point, and if the distance to the closest two seed points is within a tolerance (~1 pixel?), make this pixel a boundary. 2: start some kind of breadth-first search from each seed point concurrently along expanding shells (ideally along rasterized spheres but I suspect that's hard to implement). If in any step a given seed's next shell overlaps with another seed's closest pixels, build a boundary and stop expanding along that direction. Former might be easier to implement, but it has to be very very slow.

In any case it doesn't seem like there are ready-made solutions for this, so the question might be too broad for Stack Overflow. And the size of your 3d array might matter a lot.
